How to add listener in cells in JTable
public class MultiComponentCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer{
    
    public MultiComponentCellRenderer() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        removeAll();
        Icon updateIcon=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/update.png"));
        Icon deleteIcon=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/delete.png"));
        JLabel updateLabel=new JLabel(updateIcon); 
        JLabel deleteLabel=new JLabel(deleteIcon); 
        
        add(updateLabel);
        add(deleteLabel);
        
        if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }

        return this;
    }
}

I call this
tableNhanVien.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setCellRenderer(new MultiComponentCellRenderer());
How to add listener in cells in JTable. Help me
I want to add listener multiple JLabel in cell JTable. Each JLabel will have different event.

Adding listeners to JButtons is much easier.

I second what Gilbert said.  Labels are not meant to respond to user input.  Don’t try to make a JLabel behave like a button.  Of course, the better approach by far is to avoid placing those update and delete functions in your JTable in the first place:  Place one update button and one delete button next to your JTable (not inside the JTable), and make those buttons’ actions apply their respective operations to the currently selected rows of the JTable.
